# HOW READ METADATA IN EXCEL SHAREPOINT FILE (JSON)

Tags: node.js, json, sharepoint

I got the data from the sharepoint but can't read the tables or the data because in JSON how can I get the value inside the metadata

```html
 spauth.getAuth(url, {          
    username:username,  
    password:password  
})  
.then(function(options){  

    console.log(listTitle)
     var headers = options.headers;  
     headers['Accept'] = 'application/json;odata=verbose';  
     // Pull the SharePoint list items  
     requestprom.get({  
     url: url+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(xxxx)",  
         headers: headers,  
         json: true  
     }).then(function(listresponse){  

        
        //  var items = listresponse.d;  
        var items = listresponse;  
         var responseJSON = [];  
         console.log(items);
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3K4X.jpg)

[Data get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEcPw.jpg)

Comment: It seems I haven't got it right. The FIle sharepoint is in the Document and it is in Sheet : Form1. how the node can be accessed here via the path. PLEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SharePoint Online, we could use Graph API to get the value of the excel.

Try this endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/domain.sharepoint.com,id,id/drives/drive id/items/item id/workbook
```

You could take a look at the following blog:
[Accessing the Excel file content](https://blog.atwork.at/post/Access-files-in-OneDrive-or-SharePoint-with-Microsoft-Graph-and-the-Excel-API)

Test result:

[image]

Official document for your reference:
[Get Worksheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)