# Read Excel file in Sharepoint using java

Tags: java, excel, sharepoint, apache-poi

I have an excel file in Sharepoint with read permissions and I need to read/download it using java. Below code example gives 403 Forbidden error. Please help me to resolve this.

```
 CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY),
                new NTCredentials("username", "password", "https://abc-my.sharepoint.com", "abc"));
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                .build();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://abc-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/personal/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%dedededed-9889-098-AAAA-wbxcdssj%7D&file=my_excel.xlsx");


            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {

                EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the following blog to authenticate requests in java code：[Java-service integration with SharePoint Online via REST API](https://www.wave-access.com/public_en/blog/2015/june/23/java-service-integration-with-sharepoint-online-via-rest-api.aspx)

Or you could read excel file with Microsoft Graph API and [granting access using SharePoint App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs).

[Microsoft Graph Auth Preview SDK for Java](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth)
[HOW READ METADATA IN EXCEL SHAREPOINT FILE (JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65695980/how-read-metadata-in-excel-sharepoint-file-json/65697109#65697109)